# prompting the user when last backup happened with date and time

Tags: android

I developed an android app in which I have added the backup option. Now, I want to add the functionality of prompting the user when they carried the last backup with date and time. And if they didnt do backup then allowing them to do backup.

Please anyone help me with this how to perform this operation?

Comment: Store the date and time of last backup in a shared preference file and query when needed subsequently and find the difference from current time. Note that if you are storing a list of backup times and not just the last backup time you need to use a database

Comment: @AnuraagBaishya if pos can u plz provide any link or tutorial on this? I tried but not able to do this

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a backup function:

```
public void backup(){
    //get time of last backup
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(
    "PrefsFile", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long lastBackup = sharedPref.getLong("BackupTime", 0);
    //if there was no previous backup, lastBackup will be 0
    if (lastBackup != 0){
        long timeDiff = time - lastBackup; //difference will be in milliseconds
        //do what you need with the time difference 
    }
    //code for backup
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putLong("BackupTime", time); //update last backup time
    editor.apply();
}
```